# soviet maps toponym or descriptor

Tags: транслитерация, английский, toponyms

i am currently working with soviet maps of Saudi Arabia dated to the 1980s, supposedly based on aerial imagery from the late 1970s. These are general topographic maps, no specific theme or even military orientation.

As somebody who doesn't speak any Russian i have a hard time with it but i am getting along. A have come across a marking that i cannot translate or understand. Could it be a toponym? In that case i would be interested in the direct transcription. Or is that some kind of descriptor, if so what does it say?

any help much appreciated!

[image: map]

Comment: “Разв.” probably means “развалины”, “ruins”. If that is correct, then this says “The ruins of Khurayyim-Sa'id”.

Comment: https://www.planinite.info/Maps/pdf/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0-1966.pdf

Comment: This is not a question about Russian language and won't help anyhow any other Russian language learners.